# How to add native unit test target to gradle on Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Currently I'm developing a mostly native Android application in Android Studio. I would like to unit test my 'business logic' c++ classes and run them together with my java unit tests. My test target should:
1. Create a library with all the code I want to test
2. Compile a test main executable
3. Execute tests
4. Make it a dependency for 'java unit test' target.

I've seen some threads which deploy googletest on target machine and execute on it - but that is not my goal. I want to run tests on host machine. Any testing framework is OK, googletest would be fine.

I started with baby steps, that is - I wanted to create a target to compile a simple executable in existing build.gradle file. I struggled badly, however. I added the following:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
model {
components {
    nativeTestSources(NativeExecutableSpec) {
        sources.cpp {
                source {
                    srcDir "testdir"
                    include "**/*.cpp"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following Error:(65, 0) Cannot add Mutate rule 'org.gradle.language.base.plugins.ComponentModelBasePlugin$Rules#closeSourcesForBinaries(org.gradle.platform.base.BinaryContainer, org.gradle.language.base.ProjectSourceSet)' for model element 'binaries' when element is in state GraphClosed.

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Ideally an existing project cointaining a similar target I could look up to. I'm yet to find one.

I use Android Studio 1.3.1 with Gradle 2.4.

Comment: has anyone solved this?